# How to disable context menu on long finger press in a webapp, and stil receive all the pointer events?

Tags: javascript, browser, touch, touch-event

In a webapp project, I need a button to respond accurately to press and release events, from any pointing device, whether it comes from the mouse, the touchscreen or any means of pointing. It should work the same on any device, be it a phone, tablet, computer with a touch monitor. The response time must be accurate without the typical 300ms delay.

A sound is supposed to start playing when the button is pressed, and stop as soon as the button is released, akin to a musical instrument or sampler board.

The `pointerdown` and `pointerup` events are sufficient to get the accurate reaction. Next problem is the context menu.

I have attempted to disable it by listening to the `contextmenu` event and using `preventDefault`. Result: the context menu is disabled as expected. But this solution has an undesirable side effect: using the touchscreen, if the long press duration is greater than the context menu delay and the `contextmenu` event fires, I do not receive the subsequent `pointerup` event and the button remain stuck in the pressed position, literally.

Is there a way to both disable the context menu and receive the subsequent pointer events?